# ¿Amazon Web Services corresponde a la temática del sitio?

Tags: discusión, temática

### Contexto

Estaba navegando por el Sitio Principal, cuando decidí buscar la etiqueta [aws](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws), correspondiente a **"Amazon Web Services"**.

Vi que esta etiqueta tiene solo **19 preguntas**, y al decidirme a buscar por otros servicios de *AWS*, tales como *RDS*, o *EBS*, no encontré ni siquiera las etiquetas creadas para estos elementos.

---

### Pregunta

> En la temática del Sitio entra las preguntas relacionadas con AWS y servicios derivados?

Mi pregunta surge a causa de la mínima cantidad de preguntas relacionadas a dicha etiqueta y a que no se encuentran mas preguntas sobre otros subtemas del mismo.

Comment: Yo diría que si tiene cabida en la temática del sitio. El numero de preguntas no debe ser relevante para decidir si cabe o no en el sitio, sino en todo caso para decidir sobre la necesidad de una etiqueta.

Comment: Yo creo que lo importante no es tanto la tecnologia si no el formato de la pregunta. Si está claro, muestra lo investigado/intentado, con ejemplo que nos contextualicen en su problema y el resultado esperado entonces bienvenida sea.

Comment: Sí es temática relevante al sitio, pero tampoco es sorprendente que haya pocas preguntas: ten en cuenta que las publicaciones sobre AWS en el sitio en inglés son sólo un 0.30% del total. Aquí ese porcentaje es más bajo (0.06%), pero teniendo en cuenta que estamos "empezando", tampoco lo vería preocupante (al menos, no de momento).

Comment: Bueno, al realizar la pregunta sobre si corresponde a la tematica del sitio, no lo hacia basandome tanto en la cantidad de preguntas referentes al tema, sino en que AWS no es un tema respectivo a programacion, incluso, osaria a decir que no es sobre un sistema operativo en especifico, por eso es que surgio la duda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estas preguntas sí las aceptamos en el sitio siempre y cuando sean escritas de manera aceptable a las normas de uso - preguntas bien investigadas, organizadas, con ejemplos si lo son necesarios, y con relación a la tecnología.

La comunidad decidirá que tipos de preguntas son valiosas y cuales se responden aquí. No veo problema con hacer preguntas sobre AWS por ahora.

Comment: Perfecto Juan! Muchas gracias por la aclaración.